# Python Logger Issue - TypeError

Tags: django

Im runnin a python script within my django app.

```
import logging,os,shelve

def logging_setup(app='default'):
    """ basic logging setup """
    logfile = '/var/log/folder/'+app+'.log'

    logger = logging.getLogger(app)
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    return loggerah man ive been slammed
```

However when I call this from within my code I get ..

```
    2014-11-26 15:24:56,977 [ERROR] 'ProcessAwareLogger' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/staging/nx/views.py", line 40, in nx_input
    crawl_data = nx_runner.main(device=serializer.data["input"])
  File "/staging/nx/runner.py", line 101, in main
    self.import_to_mongo()
  File "/staging/nx/runner.py", line 69, in import_to_mongo
    mongo_import.import_all_devices()
  File "/staging/nx/parser.py", line 194, in import_all_devices
    device_model = self.import_device(d)
  File "/staging/nx/parser.py", line 158, in import_device
    self.dstoreimport(str(aggrs))
TypeError: 'ProcessAwareLogger' object is not callable
```

I calling it via ....

```
self.dstoreimport = logging_setup(app="dataImportMongo")
self.dstoreimport(str(aggrs))
```

Any ideas ..?

Comment: We can't help without seeing *exactly* how you are "calling this from within the code" and the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
self.dstoreimport(str(aggrs))
```

try

```
self.dstoreimport.info(str(aggrs))
```

instead.

`self.dstoreimport` is a logger object, and therefore not callable (hence the error). You need to call the instance method of that object (in this example, I'm using `info()`, but you could easily call `debug()`, `error()`, etc. depending on your need) instead.

Comment: sometimes its the easiest of things that can catch up out. : ) Thanks